# c++: [Error] expected initializer before 'map'

Tags: c++

Im just starting to learn c++ and i cant figure out how should i add to fix this error expected initializer before ' '

code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 char acoustic, electric, drums, piano, music, equip, Yes, No, y;

 int pay1, pay2, pay3, pay4, pay5, quantity1, quantity2, quantity3, quantity4, quantity5, map, 
 quantities, it, price_list;
 std::string again;

 int main()
    map<string, double> price_list = {{"ga1", 6900.0}, {"ga2", 6300.0}, {"ge1", 8500.0}, {"ge2", 25000.0}};
    map<string, int> quantities;
```

Comment: `int main() {...`

Comment: You need a `#include <map>`

Answer (score 0):

Likely the missing map header. Here is a compiling example. If you are using g++ make sure and compile with --std=c++11. namespace std you had is fine, I just tend to prefer to spell out the namespace for clarity; when you have lots of namespaces, it can be clearer. Hope this helps you:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::map< std::string, double > m;

    m.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("key1"), 1.0));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("key2"), 2.0));

    for (auto i : m) {
        std::cout << i.first << " = " << i.second << std::endl;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: "_namespace std you had is fine_" - how's that? It seems unreasonable with all the "namespace std" collisions spotted here.

Comment: Technically "namespace std" is acceptable syntax and it makes your code shorter. The disadvantage is loss of clarity when you have many namespaces. If maintaining a large code base, knowing where a function resides (which namespace) can help. It's a balance of ease of use vs maintainability.

Comment: Technically C++ allows a lot of things. A "_large_" code base being the basis of not using "`namespace std;`" is a _very late_ in the process restriction. Just don't use it - unless you know why - and scope it properly.